# Java processs ends overnight

Tags: java

I have jar file that I have written which is intended to search for a particular process and write this to a log file. It appears to run fine during the day, however overnight between 11pm to 1am it stopped on all 3 machines I was running it on (not all at the same time).

It is started by a scheduled task which calls the below `.bat` file at 6am every day.

```
@echo off
taskkill /IM javaw.exe /F

start javaw -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m E:\tools\Process_monitor\process_mon.jar
Console.exe E:\tools\Process_monitor\logs\console.log
```

Is it likely that it stops due to 1024m not being enough memory, or could it be some other exception that I am not catching?

Any other tips are greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length == 0){
      System.out.println("Proper usage is: process_mon.jar process_name log_file");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    String process = args[0];
    String logFile = args[1];
    String line;

    // Delete old log file
    File file = new File(logFile);
    file.delete();

    // Create logger
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Log");
    FileHandler fh;

    try {
      fh = new FileHandler(logFile);
      logger.addHandler(fh);
      SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
      fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Check for process 
    try {
      while (true){
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Process proc = null;
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq " + process + "\"");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
        oStream.write("process where name=" + process);
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
        // Read output of tasklist and write to logfile

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
          logger.info(line);
          Thread.sleep(1800);
        }
        //input.close();
      }
    } catch (
      IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      } 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Closing resources is at least one of the issues. Write a finally block and close `input` and `oStream`. Else those objects might fill up your memory.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the exception generated? If so, please add to your question.

Comment: You should catch standard error and output and look what is written there.

Comment: Why one does not simply read and/or provide exception causing app shutdown? Redirect `stderr` to file or start using some logging framework (`logback` would be just fine)

Comment: or you can edit you bat file, not using start and add a pause at end, maybe you can get the exception in the console

Comment: C'mon! 1G of memory for a simple tool like that? This would be enough for a serious app server. And 1G of stack is definitely oversized, i'd just run that tool with default settings. Maybe attach `jvisualvm` to the running process and see if if you can spot an memory leak.

Comment: Maybe the system goes into powersave mode or it reboots once a night to install updates?